# Is there any way to clear out the "Testers" field in Microsoft Test Manager (or in TFS)

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

Seems like once you set the Testers field on a Test Case in MTM, it will not allow you to clear it.  You are only allowed to change it to a different value.  Has anyone found a way to clear this field?

Comment: This field is never empty. Even when you initially add test cases to test suites, by default sets as 'tester' the person that the test case is assigned to.

Comment: I see that field as being blank.  My suites are query-based

Comment: Without customizing the workitems, there is no way to blank it out once set.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to not get the "Assigned" Tester field confused with the Assigned To field. They are distinct fields on a Test Case work item. One reason why someone might want the Tester field to be blank is if a team all pitches in to help with testing during an iteration and leaving the assigned tester blank allows the team to know that no one has "picked up" this test to execute. The team member could then assign the test to his or herself and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

The template pulls the Assigned Tester Values from a list using the 'AllowedValues' tag.  Instead, simply change this to 'SuggestedValues'.  That will allow for empty values - easy as that.

If you'd rather not allow free entry, you can also add a default value such as 'None' and use that rather than blank.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've customized your work item type, this field should never be blank after being saved. It defaults to the person who created the bug in all Microsoft supported process templates, and a value is required by default.

That being said, why would you want to change it to blank?

If you really, really want to be able to blank it out (which I don't think is a good idea at all), you'll need to customize your template. See the below guidance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243849(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For us, the owner of the test case (assigned to) is not the same as the person assigned to execute the test (tester). Putting a value in the assigned to field only nets us a bunch of automated emails.